# What is NaNi, and how is it different fron NaN?

Tags: matlab

I am writing a function in Matlab. There should be something wrong. The output of my function is a vector. When I see every element of my vector I see `NaN` (Not a Number) and `NaNi`, that really I don´t Know?

Does anybody know what is `NaNi?`

Comment: Omae wa mou shindeiru.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`NaNi` is an imaginary [Not-A-Number](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nan.html):

```
>>NaN*i
ans =
            0 +        NaNi
```

Comment: @High Performance Mark: I'm wondering whether it's possible to be even less than a number than this.

Comment: I disagree with this interpretation. _NaNi_ does not exit per se. The correct explanation is given by @Dennis Jaheruddin where NaNi is the console concatenation of _NaN_ and _i_ (the matlab imaginary notation).

Answer (score 4):

Actually NaNi does not exist in Matlab.

when you have a complex number, the displayed values are 'the real part' + 'the complex part' + 'i'. This is shown without a space before the i, try:

```
(-1)^0.5   %This will give 0.0000 + 1.0000i
```

This means that if the complex part of the number is NaN, it is printed together with i and appears to be a single word NaNi. For example:

```
NaN*(1+i)   % This will give NaN +    NaNi
x = NaN*i   % This will give 0 +    NaNi
```

You will find that it is not possible to separately evaluate NaNi or multiply it with 1.

Furthermore the expected outputs are produced when inspecting the result:

```
real(x) % This will give 0
imag(x) % This will give NaN
```